# Starting a project and leaving behind the git history

Tags: git, repository, rebase, conflict

I have a project where I feel I would prefer to leave all the long and ugly GIT history behind and start afresh.

(A reason is that merging produces a zillion conflicts in hundreds of files and resolving then is too tedious and tiresome to consider.  I have yet to discover how to say use **all** my working 'new_features' branch in merging to old master branch).

Should I start a new GIT repository locally and on GitHub and add the working version files to the new repos?

Or should I try to use git rebase?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to decide if a specific commit is not to be revisited because of a problem, for example, the chance of this situation to occur is quite high, in the future, making changes would be quite harder, if you do not have the commits.

You can use the `git clone` with `--no-single-branch` parameter, this would fetch the histories near the tips of all branches. Another parameter `--shallow-since=<date>`
Create a shallow clone with a history after the specified time. This would keep some of the more recent commits, if you feel you or your team, could be revisiting the commits soon, but not keep commits for longer than the date specified.

More parameters information for `git clone` in the Git documentation,
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Comment: This is all really helpful (though I am still trying to fully digest and perhaps rehearse with a dummy repos) .  However perhaps I should have explained why I have so many conflicts.  It is because is have dozens of generated files from Boost.Quickbook and Doxygen. Obviously, minor changes in C++ or docs will cause many changes in the generated html files. I want the generated files included in what I push to my GitHub repos so that GitHub can generate a https://pabristow.github.<my_project>.io for each repos.  But perhaps I am wrong in trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question:

1. Should I start a new history?  (Or if not, I could do fancy rebase work or something)
2. How do I start a new history?

The answer to question 1 is opinion-based, which makes it mostly off-topic (but see sidebar below).  The answer to question 2 is technical, so that's what's here:

#### Method A: a totally new repository

History *is* commits; commits are history; that's all there is.  (Well, *annotated* tags add a bit of information that's outside the commits.  Whether you want to consider the annotations "history" is up to you.)

To start a new history, you can just make an empty repository:

```
mkdir new-empty-repo
cd new-empty-repo
git init
```

Populate the working tree with files and `git add` them, and then `git commit` to make the very first commit.  Presto, you have one commit as your (entire) history.  Creating the first commit also creates the (single) branch.

No branch names can exist until there is at least one commit.  After that, an infinite number of branch names are *allowed*, though all of them must select the single commit, since that's all there is.  Once you create a *second* commit, you can still have an infinite number of branch names, and now each one can select either the first commit or the second commit.

If your Git is modern enough, you can tell it which branch name is to be created at `git init` time.  Otherwise, after `git init`, run `git checkout -b main` to switch the branch name to be created to `main`, for instance.  Once you have your first commit, creating a new branch name will link that new branch name to the (single) commit:

```
A   <-- main
```

Making a new commit will update whichever branch name you're "on" right now, so that it points to the *new* commit instead of whatever commit it used to point-to:

```
A <-B   <-- main
```

As you make more and more commits, each commit points backwards to the previous commit:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-G <-H   <-- main
```

(once you have eight commits in total).  Here, the uppercase letters stand in for the actual hash IDs of real commits.  Actual hash IDs are too big and ugly and impossible for humans to deal with (though computers are good at that), so in my drawings for StackOverflow I just use uppercase letters like this.

#### Method B: an "orphan branch"

If you like, you can keep all your existing branches, but make a new branch that will have, as its first and only commit, a commit that has no history.  That is, for the purpose of making the *next* commit, we set things up as if you'd just made a new and totally-empty repository.

The tricky part of this is that the old `git checkout` command is slightly defective; this has been corrected in the newfangled `git switch`.  At least, it's defective / corrected if you agree with the Git folks.

The idea here is simple enough.  Remember that each commit, *except for the very first commit ever made*, records a *previous* commit.  This is, after all, how history works in Git: a new commit links back to the commit you were using when you made it.  But when you make the very first commit, in a new and totally-empty repository, there *is no existing commit* that you start from.  So there's nothing to link back to.  That's how we got:

```
A   <-- main
```

above: `A` was the *first* commit, so it doesn't connect to a previous commit.  This makes commit `A` a *root* commit.

But: what if we already have some commits, on (say) `master`, like this:

```
... <-G <-H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

I've added `HEAD` to the drawing to remember which branch name we're using.

Normally, if we create a *new* branch with, e.g., `git checkout -b main`, we get this:

```
... <-G <-H   <-- main (HEAD), master
```

with both names pointing to existing commit `H`.  That way when we make a new commit `I`, the name `main` will update to point to `I`, and `I` will point back to `H`.

To get back to the sort of "virgin repository" state we had back when there were *no* commits yet, we need to "create" the new branch name without actually **creating** the new branch name.  That is, Git has to say that we're `on branch main`, but not yet *have* a branch name `main`.  There's no proper way to draw this, in the notation I use, but:

```
git checkout --orphan main
```

or:

```
git switch --orphan main
```

will do the trick.  We'll come back to the "defect" with `git checkout` in a bit.

At this point, Git has attached `HEAD` to a branch name that *does not exist*.  Running `git status` will say `on branch main`, but `git branch` won't *list* `main` as a branch name, and no *listed* name will be starred.  You are, in other words, on a branch that does not exist—the same situation you are in when you make a totally empty repository.

At this point, creating a *new* commit, well, creates a new commit.  That *creates the branch*, just as with the empty-repository case.  But since the branch didn't exist until then, the new commit *does not link back to any existing commit*.  So:

```
... do some work ...
git commit
```

results in:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master

I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

You have a new history, unrelated to the existing history.  This repository now has two branches; one has eight commits, and one has one commit.

You can now do whatever you like with the various commits, including add more commits.  You can create new branches that link back to commit `I` or any commits that link back to commit `I`, too.  This is simply a new beginning, in the same old repository.

#### `git checkout --orphan` vs `git switch --orphan`

It's time to talk about Git's index.  Any proper Git tutorial *needs* to talk about Git's index, because this is how Git makes new commits.

A *commit*, in Git, is a two-part entity:

- Each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  These are compressed, frozen, Git-ified, and importantly, de-duplicated, since most commits mostly just re-use some other commit's files.  They are, in other words, *archived*.  You can't actually *use* these files: they have to be copied and expanded out, before they become useful.
- And, each commit holds some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why (their log message).  In the metadata, Git keeps the backwards-pointing history links.  This stuff is also frozen.  It's literally impossible to change any part of any commit, once it's written into the Git database-of-all-commits-and-supporting-objects.

The thing is, though, Git doesn't *make* these commits from the files you see and edit.  Instead, Git inserts this extra thing—Git's *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*—in between the *current commit* and your files.

What's in the index is—at least initially—the Git-ified copy of each file from the commit.  But these file copies not exactly read-only at this particular point: if you overwrite one of these files, Git unlinks it from the sharing, and Git-ifies the *new* data.  Now what's in the index is the *proposed next commit*.

In fact, what was in the index before was *also* the proposed next commit.  It's just that it matched the *actual, current* commit.  There's no point re-committing until you update Git's index.

The way you update Git's index is to work with the files in your working tree.  These are ordinary, non-Git-ified files, that every program can actually *use*.  Once you've *changed* one, or added a new one, or removed one, **now** you need to tell Git: *Hey, update the proposed commit now, I made some changes!*  You do this with `git add`, usually, or sometimes with `git rm`.  The `git rm` command conveniently removes both the working tree copy of a file *and* the staged copy, at the same time.

When you run `git commit`, Git:

- packages up whatever is in Git's index *right then;*
- adds the appropriate metadata, including using the current commit's hash ID as the parent for the new commit;
- writes all that out as a commit, freezing it for all time; and
- writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name.

When you're in that special "virgin" state—on a branch that doesn't exist—the metadata for the new commit *doesn't* list a parent, making the new commit a new root commit.  The writing of the hash ID *creates* the branch name.

Now, `git checkout --orphan` and `git switch --orphan` *both* set up this "virgin" state for the *branch*.  The difference between these two commands is what they do with Git's *index* and your working tree.

The `git checkout --orphan` command *does nothing at all with Git's index and your working tree*.  So if your index and working tree contain various *tracked* files—a tracked file is just one that's in Git's index—then after `git checkout --orphan`, your index and working tree are *still* full of tracked files.

You can use this to good effect: making a new commit now makes a commit that matches the commit you checked out earlier, assuming of course you didn't make any changes since then and `git add` them.

The Git folks, however, decided that this is the wrong way for Git to behave.  So if you use `git switch --orphan` to set yourself up, *this* command will *empty out Git's index* by removing every file from it.  At the same time, Git will remove the working tree copy of the file.  (Before Git does either one, it will make sure that the index and working-tree copies match the committed copy, of course.  Otherwise this could destroy unsaved work.)

So, if you *want* the files from the commit you had checked out earlier, and you use `git switch --orphan`, you will need to use `git restore` to get the files back into Git's index and/or your working tree.  But if you use `git checkout --orphan` they will just be there, and if you *don't* want the files, you will need to use `git rm` to clean them out.

That's the big difference between `git checkout --orphan` and `git switch --orphan`: the `switch` variant erases your index and all the corresponding working-tree files.  The `checkout` variant doesn't.

#### Sidebar: "messy" vs "clean" history

You did mention *why* you want to start a new history:

> merging produces a zillion conflicts in hundreds of files and resolving then is too tedious and tiresome to consider

This sort of problem *should* only happen once (per branch, perhaps, and may also depend on how you go about resolving things).

Real history often *is* messy, sometimes very messy.  Some Git users put a fair amount of work into producing less-messy histories.  This has some advantages: it's a lot easier to read and think about the cleaned-up history, and often, the fact that someone made a bunch of tiny mistakes is totally irrelevant, for instance.  But sometimes it's important to record a mistake, either because it got out into the wild and may need to be dealt with, or because it's easy to make *again* and we should keep it in mind and (a) avoid making it again and/or (b) show how to fix it.

So there are definitely some advantages to keeping the real history.  It also means less time spent on "clean history", leaving more time to get sh... er, stuff, done.  Everyone needs to evaluate this tradeoff for themselves, in the end.